# Ext JS 4 - how to create multiple store instances and assign to views? (MVC)

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, grid, instance

How do you create unique instances of stores and assign them to views (I am ok with creating unique views and/or controllers if that's required)?

A simple use case - I want to open multiple grid's (of the same type) with a list of records from a store in each.   Each grid would need to have it's own store instance, because it could have it's own list of records, it's own filtering, etc. etc.

I tried this, but it does not work, my grids do not draw:

```
 var theView = Ext.create('App.view.encounter.List');
    theView.title = 'WORC Encounters';
    var theStore=Ext.create('App.store.Encounters');
    theView.store=theStore;
    tabhost.add({title:'WORC',items:theView});

    var theView = Ext.create('App.view.encounter.List');
    theView.title = 'NC Encounters';
    var theStore2=Ext.create('App.store.Encounters');
    theView.store=theStore2;
    tabhost.add({title:'NC',items:theView});
```

Comment: Hi, Even I am in similar situation. Have you found any answer to this?

Comment: No, unfortunately for this and several other reasons I have put my extjs development on hold and am using a different platform (non js based).

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the store when the component is initializing (or before). In the initComponent.

```
Ext.define('classname', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    //...
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        var theStore = Ext.create('App.store.Encounters');
        Ext.apply(me, {
            store: theStore
        }); 

        me.callParent();
    }
    //...
});
```

You could also do it this way:

```
//Create the store
var theStore = Ext.create('App.store.Encounters');
//Create the view
var theView = Ext.create('App.view.encounter.List', {
     store: theStore
});
```

Edit for you example specific:

```
var theStore = Ext.create('App.store.Encounters');
var theView = Ext.create('App.view.encounter.List', {
       title:  'WORC Encounters',
       store: theStore
});
tabhost.add({title:'WORC',items:theView});


var theStore2=Ext.create('App.store.Encounters');
var theView2 = Ext.create('App.view.encounter.List', {
       title: 'NC Encounters',
       store: theStore2
});
tabhost.add({title:'NC',items:theView2});
```

Comment: I see 1 store, so where is the second?

Comment: You just define the second store in your other view, it's the same way of working. There's no use of defining the second store in the same view...

Comment: ok, so just to help me understand, it looks like the difference between your code and mine is the "Ext.apply", correct?

Comment: Apply does basically the same as `me.store = store`. The big difference is that i'm assigning my store at the initialization. And not after the initialization like you're doing. Look my edit for your example specific.